# How to make square raised buttons in Flutter?

Tags: android, button, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I've got a whole bunch of `RaisedButton`s in a Wrap, so that they can take up as many rows as they need. But I do want to expand the buttons into square buttons. I can do that by replacing the `Wrap` with a `GridView.count` and using the `crossAxisCount`, but then when more real estate is available, the buttons become unnecessarily large. Basically, I want them all to be squares of the same size, all only as large as the content they hold. They're not dynamically loaded or anything, so there's no concerns about performance. But we are looking at the possibility of fairly small screens, so scrolling needs to be possible as well. Is there a way to get all these things right?

Here's the current code and what it produces:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Wrap(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {}
            label: Text('Park In', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          RaisedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {}
            label: Text('Park Out', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.eject),
          ),
          RaisedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {}
            label: Text('Maintainence In', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.vertical_align_bottom),
          ),
          RaisedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {}
            label: Text('Maintainence Out', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.vertical_align_top),
          ),
          RaisedButton.icon(
            onPressed: null,
            label: Text('Move', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.open_with),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Current result]

Replacing with a GridView with 2 as the `crossAxisCount` gives this, which is very close to what I need (ideally the text would be bigger and wrap - it seems to overflow if not given the right space, but I suppose I can deal with that when it comes to that):

[image: Gridview almost there]

But then when I go to, for example, landscape mode, where easily 3 buttons can fit in one row, the GridView just goes "eh, whatever" and makes the buttons enormous:

[image: GridView bad]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `OrientationBuilder` for that. It will take care of orientation changes for you:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("word"),
    ),
    body: OrientationBuilder(
      builder: (context, orientation) {
        int count = 2;
        if(orientation == Orientation.landscape){
          count = 3;
        }
        return GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: count,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {},
              label: Text('Park In', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
            RaisedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {},
              label: Text('Park Out', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
              icon: Icon(Icons.eject),
            ),
            RaisedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {},
              label:
                  Text('Maintainence In', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
              icon: Icon(Icons.vertical_align_bottom),
            ),
            RaisedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {},
              label:
                  Text('Maintainence Out', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
              icon: Icon(Icons.vertical_align_top),
            ),
            RaisedButton.icon(
              onPressed: null,
              label: Text('Move', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
              icon: Icon(Icons.open_with),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it not true that the number of buttons that can fit will change because of screen size? Though I suppose then dynamically calculating it with width and height could work. Fair enough, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `AspectRatio`

```dart
AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: 1,
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('hi'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I got "This RenderAspectRatio was given an aspect ratio of 1.0 but was given both unbounded width and unbounded height constraints. Because both constraints were unbounded, this render object doesn't know how much size to consume."

Comment: You can wrapped it by `SizedBox` for fixed sizes or `Expanded` for flexed size.
The main idea here is make each widget do their own things. In this case, `AspectRatio` will keep the ratio of widget not their bounds.

Answer (score 1):

As of now flutter 3.3.10 Raised Button is not supported.
But you can use other buttons like TextButton,
To achieve this you just need to wrap it inside AspectRatio widget

Like in previous example

```
AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: 1,
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('hi'),
  ),
);
```

Do not put the AspectRatio widget within unbounded height or width widgets to avoid rendering errors.